# Hierarchy of project in maven

Tags: java, maven

Situation with inheritance in maven. I want create hierarchy of projects.
Something like main `POM <- module1 <- module2.`

I trying in my main POM to define module1 with `<module> module1</module>`. In module2 i define parent POM with `<parent>` tag. But after comand "mvn clean package" in main project folder, there is no jar created in the module2 directory.

can someone explain me what i have to do.
Thanks.

Comment: The error you are getting would help

Comment: module1 must have POM packaging.

Comment: `<parent>` is not the inverse of `<module>`, by the way.  It is not necessary for a module's `<parent>` to be the directory above.

Comment: can you post pom along with dir structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the child project into your local repository and include it in the list of dependencies in your parent project. If you're not making changes often to the child project then I've found the install+refresh is quicker overall than having your IDE constantly scanning multiple projects to resolve dependencies.

Comment: -1 Reason: this can lead to instable builds on a continuous integration server. If you want to do something similar, then versionized the child project properly (not a SNAPSHOT version) and deploy it to a repository manager such as Nexus. Then you can declare a dependency to that artifact.

Answer (score 0):

> module1 must have POM packaging

And there you have your answer. Only modules with POM packaging can contain other modules.

Comment: So we can't create hierarhy with out POM packaging in intermediate POM ?

Comment: That's correct AFAIK. It's not a big limitation though, I guess.